# Database Table Design: normalization or not

Tags: mysql, database, database-performance, database-normalization

A Web Configurator (for customizable electronic articles) shall persist a user-generated configuration via a web user interface to a MySQL-database.

The available options are static, amount of 10 to 20 different options.

I cannot figure out which solution has more advantages. And I am asking for some advice, because this is a common question in database design.

## Solution #1

1 table:

configurations:

- id
- option1
- option2
- option3
- etc.

## Solution #2

2 tables and 1 relationTable (see below)

configurations:

- id

options:

- id
- name
- value

It does not matter to me whether it will be a unidirectinal OneToMany association with a join table or unidirectional ManyToOne association with a foreignKey on the option's side.

The question is, whether to have **one table** with about **10 to 20 columns**, each for each option, eventually, the need to alter the database schema from time to time, if new options are required

*OR*

to have for every configuration entry about **10 to 20 associated option entries**.

the configurations table could grow to about 2000 configurations per month => 20000 to 40000 option entries per month.

The query time to query a configuration and its associated options, if the options table has more than 1.000.000 entries could be high, right (Solution #1)? Is it a better option to query a row of a single table with about 20 columns (Solution #1)?
Perhaps this is also a criterion.
Are there drawbacks / pros / cons for any solution?

Comment: IMHO: If each option have to be present for each configuration, then Solution 1 . Otherwise the Solution 2. It is just more stable.

Comment: @Mikey Some options may be nullable, so solution one would be still an option. Solution 2 is more stable to enhancements, but I am wondering if the queries will be to imperformant. I will just edit my post and mention that thought. Thanks!

Comment: So some options are not nullable? Those options have to be in the same table (not nullable columns). In other case one can not ensure their presence. The performance may be an issue, but its a optimisation: a little to early for that and modern data bases are pretty good at joins.

Comment: This reorganization from 1 to 2 is not normalization.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Solution #2.  I would also add caching layer to the application for `options` table which will create for each `configuration_id` requested, a json object (array, list or whatever your language supports) with all options already queried, processed and ready to use.